# Asp .net MVC3 user registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I am teaching myself Asp .net MVC 3. I have reached a stage where I need to now incorporate user account system. I started with standard Asp .net MVC 3 membership provider and want to stick with it for most part and store all other user details in another table linked to users table.

However, I would like to add two features at the time of registration:
1) Confirmation Email
2) Accept T&C.

Is there an easy way to do this without building a custom membership provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I don't believe confirmations emails/terms and conditions should be part of a membership provider.

You normally would deal with things like that in your AccountController (or whatever equivalent you have).

For instance, if you have a Register action, once you've used the membership provider to save a user and everything looks good, you would then send out the confirmation email (code being triggered from the action)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the accept terms and conditions to the RegisterModel class in the Account Model (AccountModels.cs in the Models directory), like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Agree to Terms")]
public bool AgreeTandC { get; set; }
```

You have to update the Register view, adding the display for this so that a Check Box will be displayed and whatever text you want with it.

Unfortunately you cannot simply use the `[Required]` attribute since this is a `bool` and not being checked is false not null. There are ways to create a custom bool required attribute but they are a bit of work. It may be easier for you to add a check in the Register method in the Account Controller to see if it is checked, something like this:

```
if(model.AgreeTandC == false)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("AgreeTandC", "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions");
    return View(model);
}
```

I haven't used the `ModelState.AddModelError` like that before but I think it will work (display the error to the user) otherwise just replace it with `ViewBag.Error = "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions";` and add this to the register view model.

As for the email, it's not hard, you have to add the ability to send email something like  [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) will help with that. You also need to change the `Membership.CreateUser` line in the Register method of the Account Controller to not authorize the user.

```
Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, false, null, out createStatus);
```

I think that is how it should be. Then if the `createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)` send the email with the confirmation GUID `string confirmationGuid = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();`

You will also have to make a method to accept the confirmation ID (when they click the link in their email.)

I just briefly touched on the email part, there are many blogs online that go into sending registration emails in complete detail.